# Massive insert sql - Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I need a query to insert rows into a table within the last N days from today.

```
Insert into Table select 'xpto', name 
from users where login_date between 
    TO_DATE(:DATE || ' 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') 
and TO_DATE(:DATE || ' 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
```

I need this **:DATE** to be represented by last 30 days... (each day)..
So it would be 30 inserts.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

Lets say I want to insert data from the last 30 days... So we have:

```
01/18/2016
01/19/2016
01/20/2016
...
02/01/2016
02/02/2016
02/03/2016
....
02/15/2016
....
02/22/2016
```

I want a single query - or statement -  to insert my data based on each days above like this:

```
Insert into Table select 'xpto', name 
from users where login_date between 
    TO_DATE('01/15/2016' || ' 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') 
and TO_DATE('01/15/2016' || ' 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
--- another insert
Insert into Table select 'xpto', name 
from users where login_date between 
    TO_DATE('01/16/2016' || ' 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') 
and TO_DATE('01/16/2016' || ' 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
```

I don't want to do one query for each day...

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I'm sorry I just got my work notebook here...here is the real sample:

```
BEGIN
for day in (SELECT to_char(TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy')-30 + LEVEL) AS DATE_CHECK
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY SYSDATE - 30 + LEVEL <= SYSDATE)
  LOOP
  v_date := to_char(day.date_check);
  INSERT INTO resume (date_check, type, total)
SELECT   v_data AS DATA, type, COUNT (*) total
    FROM ( select ....
 from table
 WHERE DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN TO_DATE(v_data ||' 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and TO_DATE(v_date || ' 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
union 
select ....
 from table
 WHERE DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN TO_DATE(v_data ||' 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and TO_DATE(v_date || ' 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
)

end loop;
end;
```

but it doesn't work... if I do the same insert manually replacing v_date by any date (14/02/2016) it works....

:(

Comment: It'd be one insert with an unknown number of rows. Maybe 30. That's not massive. Anyway you can use `BETWEEN sysdate - 30 AND sysdate` to do what you're after.

Comment: Its was just an example.. I need an extraction withing at least 2 years... so I have to do a big insert query... and its not between `sysdate - 30 and sysdate`.. its more like it was in a loop.. for each day in the last X days, get the date and filter..

Comment: I don't see any requirement for a loop so far. You need to explain what you mean by 'for each day in the last X days get the date and filter'. In what way does a standard 'between' not function for you? Perhaps post sample data

Comment: Are you trying to insert many rows for each user?

Comment: Another edit guys..... I think I've passed the wrong idea...sorry

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly the following might serve:

```
Insert into Table
  select 'xpto', name 
    from users
    where login_date between TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '30' DAY
                         and TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
```

### EDIT

Based on the edit to the question it appears that we can just expand the range, as in:

```
Insert into Table
  select 'xpto', name 
    from users
    where login_date between TO_DATE('01/18/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
                         and TO_DATE('02/22/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
```

### SECOND EDIT

Thank you for clarifying. Perhaps the following will help:

```
BEGIN
  for day in (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)-30 + LEVEL AS DATE_CHECK
                FROM DUAL
                CONNECT BY TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30 + LEVEL <= TRUNC(SYSDATE))
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO resume (date_check, type, total)
      SELECT day.DATE_CHECK AS DATA, type, COUNT (*) total
        FROM (select ....
                from table
                WHERE DATE_COLUMN = TRUNC(day.DATE_CHECK));
  end loop;
end;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: I just edited the question with a better explanation Bob... can you please take a look? :)

Comment: Added second example - although the first doesn't require editing every time you want to run the query. Best of luck.

Comment: what if I need to insert each day (mm/dd/yyyy) of the "loop"?

Comment: If I've understood your requirement, I don't see that there's any need for a loop. It appears to me that you have a start date and an end date, and need all the data with LOGIN_DATEs between the start and end value. Additionally, in SQL there's no loop construct - everything is done by generating a set of data and operating on that set (or sets). If you were using PL/SQL (Oracle's language which can be thought of as "Ada with embedded SQL") you could use a loop - but in pure SQL there is neither a need for nor a way to code a loop, in traditional programming terms.

Comment: That's twice you've said 'not working'. Third time you get struck by lightening. Please explain the outcome instead of saying 'now working'. Based on all of the text in this question I still fail to see why a 30 day BETWEEN range will do not do what you expect. The one difference I see is that because you have a `UNION` it's selecting distinct records between the two days.

Comment: The date format in the first edit was incorrect so I touched that up.

Comment: Well....if I knew the explanation I'd have posted here.... apparently it's everything fine with bob's query.... but it doesn't insert any rows.. there is no outcome.. it doesn't give exceptions or something usefull.. it's like there is not data to insert but there are. If I put the date manually, works...if I put the data ranging each date in last 30 days loop, it doesn't work (I hope I don't get struck by lightening xD). Nick, I'm sorry if i'm been clear here but if I get a 30 day between range I would be extraction my data monthly, I need it to be daily in the last 30 days..got it?